# Randomly Access in a Priority Queue

Tags: c++, data-structures, priority-queue

How i can access/search randomly in  a priority queue?. for example, if have a priority queue like q={5,4,3,2,1} for example, i want to access 3rd value directly which is 3, i could not do this,is there any process to access randomly in priority queue?

Comment: What language and class?

Comment: A queue is a queue is a queue... It's not supposed to be accessed in a random access manner.

Comment: you can't, that's the point of a priority queue. you could just pop 3 times, but... maybe use a sorted list instead?

Comment: in c++ @user3612643

Comment: I have to disagree. It's possible. You can implement all sorts of queues that also allow random access, delete or update.

Comment: @Ramzan what class?

Comment: i am new in priority queue, thanks for your comment  @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: but i need full queue after random access that's why i can't pop any element @1blustone

Comment: Class means? @user3612643

Comment: @user3612643 not just any queue, a min/max-heap - you can't just get the third element in a heap because you don't know what it is. all you know is what the current max/min is.

Comment: Now i understand,  thanks @1blustone

Comment: For all the haters, actually c++ deque have O(1) random access. the problen with priority queue is that it has a tree like structure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most priority queue implementations, including the C++ `std::priority_queue` type, don't support random access. The idea behind a priority queue is to sacrifice random access for fast access to the smallest element.

Depending on what you're trying to do, there are a number of other approaches you could use. If you *always* want access to the third element in the queue (and not any other arbitrary positions), it's probably fast enough to just dequeue two elements, cache them, then dequeue the value you want and put the other two elements back.

If you want access to the kth-smallest element at any point in time, where k is larger, one option is to store two different priority queues: a reverse-sorted priority queue that holds k elements (call it the left queue) and a regular priority queue holding the remaining n-k elements (call it the right queue). To get the kth-smallest element, dequeue from the left queue (giving back the kth-smallest element), then dequeue an element from the right and enqueue into the left to get it back up to k total elements. To do an enqueue, check if the number is less than the top of the left queue. If so, dequeue from the left queue, enqueue the removed element into the right queue, then enqueue the original element into the left. Otherwise, enqueue into the right. This guarantees O(log n) runtimes for each operation.

If you need true random access to a sorted sequence, consider using an order statistics tree. This is an augmented binary search tree that supports O(log n) access to elements by index. You can use this to build a priority queue - the minimum element is always at index 0. The catch (of course there's a catch) is that it's hard to find a good implementation of one and the constant factors hidden in the O(log n) terms are much higher than in a standard binary heap.

Comment: actually, for solving a problem in a online judge, i need to do this type of access. i am new in priority queue.  by the way now i understand all of this. and thank you  for your answer

Comment: Another way to access a priority queue by index is with an [indexable skiplist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist). And its constant factors aren't bad at all.

Comment: @JimMischel That's true! Indexable skiplists are essentially isomorphic to order statistic trees, just represented differently.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer of @templatetypedef:

You cannot combine random access of elements with a priority queue, unless you use a very inefficient priority queue. Here's a few options, depending on what you need:

1- An inefficient priority queue would be a `std::vector` that you keep sorted. Pushing an element means finding where it should be inserted, and move all subsequent elements forward. Popping an element would be simply reading and deleting the last element (`back` and `pop_back`, these are efficient). Random access is efficient as well, of course.

2- You could use a `std::multiset` (or `std::multimap`) instead of a priority queue. It is a tree structure that keeps things sorted. You can `insert` instead of `push`, then read and remove the first (or last) element using a `begin` (or `rbegin`) iterator with `erase`. Insertion and finding the first/last element are log(n) operations. The data structure allows for reading all elements in order, though it doesn't give random access.

3- You could hack your own version of `std::priority_queue` using a `std::vector` and the `std::push_heap` and `std::pop_heap` algorithms (together with the `push_back` and `pop_back` methods of the `std::vector`). You'd get the same efficient priority queue, but also random access to all elements of the priority_queue. They are not sorted, all you know is that the first element in your array is the top priority element, and that the other elements are stored in a way that the heap property is satisfied. If you only occasionally want to read all elements in order, you can use the function `std::sort_heap` to sort all elements in your array by priority. The function `std::make_heap` will return your array to its heap status.

Note that `std::priority_queue` uses a `std::vector` by default to store its data. It might be possible to `reinterpret_cast` the `std::priority_queue` to a `std::vector`, so you get random access to the other elements in the queue. But if it works on your implementation of the standard library, it might not on others, or on future versions of the same library, so I don't recommend you do this! It's safer to create your own heap class using the algorithms in the standard library as per #3 above.

Comment: [Indexable skiplist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist) gives you O(log n) access by order, O(log n) insert, O(1) delete-min. It *is* possible to combine efficient random access with a priority queue.

Comment: @JimMischel: A skiplist is not something I had thought about. Interesting idea. We'd have to test this to make sure, but I'd be willing to bet that you need a very, very large list to make it more efficient than a `std::vector` with sorted entries. Shifting entries in an array is pretty quick, even if it is O(n). In contrast, all the extra storage needed for skiplists, and all the pointers to follow, would make cache misses more common.

Comment: @Chris: certainly a skip list requires more memory: average two forward pointers per node. An array would undoubtedly be faster for a small list. I suspect the skip list would be faster for a list longer than 1K items. Quite possibly even a shorter list. But, as with anything performance related, profile to be sure.